# lein cljsbuild gives "Could not write JavaScript nil" error

Tags: clojurescript, leiningen, cljsbuild

Every time I try to run `lein cljsbuild once` I get an error:

> Could not write JavaScript nil

Any thoughts or ideas would be appreciated as I have been stuck on this for a while and unfortunately cannot go any further.

Here is what I have been doing.

1. Create a new project called finance by runnin `lein new app finance`
2. Update the `project.clj` file with dependencies, cljsbuild, plugin and main spec(see below)
3. Run `lein deps` and this works.
4. Run `lein run` and that also works, spitting out 'Hello World' in the console.
5. Try to run `lein cljsbuild once` and then I get this error that `Could not write JavaScript nil`

   ```
   (defproject finance "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
           :description "FIXME: write description"
           :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.7"]]
           :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
           :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
                     :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
           :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]
                          [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.238"]
                          [reagent "0.8.0-alpha2"]]
           :main ^:skip-aot finance.core
           :target-path "target/%s"
           :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}}
           :cljsbuild {
               :builds [{
                   :source-paths ["src"]
                   :compiler {
                       :output-to "resources/public/javascripts/dev.js"
                       :output-dir "resources/public/javascripts/cljs-dev"
                       :optimizations :none
                       :pretty-print true}}]})
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start over in a new directory.  Your error was using `app` instead of `figwheel` in creating the project:

```
> lein new figwheel fred
> cd fred
> lein cljsbuild once      ; => works fine
> lein figwheel            ; => starts interactive browser repl
```

Normally you would just use `figwheel`, but `cljsbuild once` also works.

Your project.clj now looks like the following. Note in particular the `:plugins` section you were missing:

```
(defproject fred "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :min-lein-version "2.7.1"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.9.946"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async  "0.4.474"]]

  :plugins [[lein-figwheel "0.5.15"]
            [lein-cljsbuild "1.1.7" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]]

  :source-paths ["src"]
  :cljsbuild {:builds
              [{:id "dev"
                :source-paths ["src"] 
                ;; The presence of a :figwheel configuration here will cause figwheel to inject the
                ;; figwheel client into your build
                :figwheel {:on-jsload "fred.core/on-js-reload"
                           ;; :open-urls will pop open your application in the default browser once
                           ;; Figwheel has started and compiled your application.  Comment this out
                           ;; once it no longer serves you.
                           :open-urls ["http://localhost:3449/index.html"]}

                :compiler {:main fred.core
                           :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
                           :output-to  "resources/public/js/compiled/fred.js"
                           :output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/out"
                           :source-map-timestamp true
                           ;; To console.log CLJS data-structures make sure you enable devtools in Chrome
                           ;; https://github.com/binaryage/cljs-devtools
                           :preloads [devtools.preload]}}
               ;; This next build is a compressed minified build for production. You can build this
               ;; with: lein cljsbuild once min
               {:id "min"
                :source-paths ["src"]
                :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/fred.js"
                           :main fred.core
                           :optimizations :advanced
                           :pretty-print false}}]}

  :profiles {:dev {:dependencies [[binaryage/devtools "0.9.9"]
                                  [figwheel-sidecar "0.5.15"]
                                  [com.cemerick/piggieback "0.2.2"]]
                   ;; need to add dev source path here to get user.clj loaded
                   :source-paths ["src" "dev"]
                   ;; for CIDER
                   ;; :plugins [[cider/cider-nrepl "0.12.0"]]
                   :repl-options {:nrepl-middleware [cemerick.piggieback/wrap-cljs-repl]}
                   ;; need to add the compliled assets to the :clean-targets
                   :clean-targets ^{:protect false} ["resources/public/js/compiled"
                                                     :target-path]}})
```

Comment: No problem.  I've also been wrestling with a CLJS config problem this week.